# Can not create a new Label in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

In this program, I have simulated a failure in a connection. At first, a "Connecting..." label is displayed. After the failure, the label will change to "Connection Failed." and a try again button is displayed. When the try again button is pressed, I want to destroy the "Connection Failed." label and create a new "Connecting..." label. The destruction happens successfully but a new "Connecting..." label can not be created and I can not see that. I also tried to modify the "Connection Failed." text to "Connecting..." using the config method but it does not work either. It is weird...

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
import signal

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
# Create main window
root = tk.Tk()

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry(f"{screen_width}x{screen_height}")
is_connection_done = tk.StringVar(value="")
try_again_button = None
connecting_message = None

def connect():
    global try_again_button, connecting_message, root
    print('Trying to connect')
    if try_again_button:
        try_again_button.destroy()
        try_again_button = None
        connecting_message.destroy()
        connecting_message = tk.Label(root, text="Connecting...")
        connecting_message.pack()
        

    time.sleep(2)
    is_connection_done.set("failed")
    
connecting_message = tk.Label(root, text="Connecting...")
connecting_message.pack()
connection_event_id = root.after(1000, connect)

while True:
    is_connection_done.set("")
    root.wait_variable(is_connection_done)
    if is_connection_done.get() == 'done':
        connecting_message.config(text='Connected Successfully!')
        break
    elif is_connection_done.get() == 'failed':
        print('Failed')
        connecting_message.config(text='Connection Failed.')
        try_again_button = tk.Button(root, text='Try Again', command=connect)
        try_again_button.pack()
        
        
# Start event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the while loop blocks `root.mainloop()` from executing, so `tkinter` mainloop cannot take control and update widgets.

You can call `connecting_message.update()` after `connecting_message.pack()` inside `connect()` to force the update.

However, it is not recommended to use while loop in a `tkinter` application.  Use `after()` instead.

```py
import time
import tkinter as tk
import signal

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
# Create main window
root = tk.Tk()

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry(f"{screen_width}x{screen_height}")
is_connection_done = tk.StringVar(value="")

def connect():
    # hide the "Try Again" button
    try_again_button.pack_forget()
    # update label text
    connecting_message.config(text="Connecting...")
    # use after() instead of time.sleep(2)
    root.after(2000, is_connection_done.set, "failed")

connecting_message = tk.Label(root, text="Connecting...")
connecting_message.pack()
connection_event_id = root.after(1000, connect)

# create the button but initially hidden
try_again_button = tk.Button(root, text='Try Again', command=connect)

def checking():
    is_connection_done.set("")
    root.wait_variable(is_connection_done)
    if is_connection_done.get() == 'done':
        connecting_message.config(text='Connected Successfully!')
        return   # stop the checking loop
    elif is_connection_done.get() == 'failed':
        connecting_message.config(text='Connection Failed.')
        # show the "Try Again" button
        try_again_button.pack()
        root.after(100, checking) # schedule next checking

# start checking loop
checking()
# Start event loop
root.mainloop()
```